# Stopping and Starting read / copy on binary file

Tags: c++, io, binary

So i'm attempting to copy a binary file up to a certain point...stop...perform some operations, then copy the remaining contents from the original binary out to my new binary. However when i perform my second read operation, my read buffer is empty. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks so much...

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);

ofstream fout("test.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

int position = getPositionX();
fin.seekg(position);
streamoff initialCopyLength = fin.tellg();
char * readBuffer = new char[initialCopyLength];
fin.seekg(0, fin.beg);
fin.read(readBuffer, initialCopyLength);
fout.write(readBuffer, initialCopyLength);

///perform some operations, then copy out the rest of the binary

int currentPosition = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
streamoff length = fin.tellg();
readBuffer = new char[length];
fin.read(readBuffer, length);
//write out last part of file
fout.write(readBuffer, length);
fin.close();
fout.close();
```

Comment: Related: You forgot to check whether reading succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek to the end of the file with `fin.seekg(0, fin.end);` but you never seek back to the read position before you try to `read()` so you read nothing as you are at the end.  You need another `seekg` call before you `read()` so you get back to where you were.  Adding

```
fin.seekg(currentPosition, fin.beg);
```

will get you back to where you were.

You also have a mistake with

```
streamoff length = fin.tellg();
```

this is giving you the total file size.  To get what is left you need

```
streamoff length = fin.tellg() - currentPosition;
```

Comment: That was definitely part of the solution. Now there is 4 million extra "Í" appended to the end of the copied file....I can only assume that the read buffer is too large?

Comment: Totally makes sense now! Thanks for the assist!!